# Don't make functions within a loop when converting image urls in object array to base64

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through a list of image_urls in an object array and convert them to base64 for later processing.

This is my code so far:

```
function findR(f, p) {
  for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    var userUpload = f.data;
    toDataUrl(p[i].image_url, function(base64Img) {
      console.log(base64Img);
    });
  }
}

function toDataUrl(src, callback, outputFormat) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    callback(dataURL);
  };
  img.src = src;
  if (img.complete || img.complete === undefined) {
    img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
    img.src = src;
  }
}
```

I keep getting the following error message: **"Don't make functions within a loop.”**. How can I restructure my code to avoid this issue?

Comment: Make the function outside the loop, and pass it the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to outsource your function (currently inside the for loop) to outside the for loop. Since javascript creates this anonymous function on every loop, you'll end up with unnecessary overhead.

Due to the nature of javascript you can write the function outside of the loop and reference it inside the loop. You could move the outsourcedFunction to the upper-most scope (just before `function findR`) if you want to use it in `toDataUrl` as well.

```
function findR(f, p) {
  // see here
  var outsourcedFunction = function(base64Img) {
      console.log(base64Img);
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    var userUpload = f.data;
    toDataUrl(p[i].image_url, outsourcedFunction);
  }
}

function toDataUrl(src, callback, outputFormat) {...}
}
```

Comment: sorrrry, too much coffee, too fast. :x